# Group and sum List

Tags: c#, list, linq, sum, linq-group

I have raw list in C# (RoomId,WallTypeId,WallTypeArea) which I need to group by the two first, then sum the third. For each room and walltype I need an area. (How much walltype in each room.) It can be done simple with a couple of `foreach` loops I guess. But there's a lot of rooms and each wall is divided into a large number of subfaces.
Does anyone know a more efficient linq and/or IEnumerable method to do this ?

Here's my class and `List<RawSurfaceData>`:

```
public class RawSurfaceData                 
{                   
    public ElementId RoomId;                    
    public ElementId WallTypeId;                    
    public double WallTypeArea;                 
}                   

RoomId  WallTypeId  WallTypeArea            
 101      WT01        10            
 101      WT01        10            
 101      WT01        10            
 101      WT03        10            
 102      WT01        10            
 102      WT01        10            
 102      WT03        10            
 102      WT03        10
```

Needs to be like this:

```
 101      WT01        30            
 101      WT03        10            
 102      WT01        20            
 102      WT03        20
```

I put together some code after researching here but it doesn't do any grouping.

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<SortedSurfaceData,RawSurfaceData>> sortedSurfData0
{
    get;
    set;
}

public void GroupRawData(List<RawSurfaceData> rawData)
{
    sortedSurfData0 = (IEnumerable<IGrouping<SortedSurfaceData, RawSurfaceData>>)rawData.GroupBy(t => new SortedSurfaceData { roomSorted = t.RoomElement, elemTypeSorted = t.elemType, dblTypeAreaInRoom = rawData.Sum(a => t.dblArea) });
}
```

Below is another attempt at doing the same thing.
It will just return one element(room) and doesn't sum correctly.

```
public void SortRoomSurfData(List<RawSurfaceData> lstRawData)
{
    var query = (from t in lstRawData
                 group t by new { t.RoomElement, t.elemType }
                 into grp
                 select new
                 {
                     grp.Key.RoomElement,
                     grp.Key.elemType,
                     Quantity = grp.Sum(t => t.dblArea)
                 });
}
```

A short video of the debugging here:
http://screencast.com/t/5EuZi1OM1l

I select two elements(rooms) in a building model.
The software API correctly returns 19 surfaces(RawSurfaceData) in total.
But `var query` only returns one room.

Comment: Sorry miken this is C#.

I put together some code but not sure what it does.
I did get some structure on "sortedSurfData0" but not what i aimed at doing. The two classes SortedSurfaceData and RawSurfaceData area bascially the same just need to group and sum.
  
        public void GroupRawData(List<RawSurfaceData> rawData)
        {
            sortedSurfData0 = (IEnumerable<IGrouping<SortedSurfaceData, RawSurfaceData>>)rawData.GroupBy(t => new SortedSurfaceData { roomSorted = t.RoomElement, elemTypeSorted = t.elemType, dblTypeAreaInRoom = rawData.Sum(a => t.dblArea) });
        }

Comment: The query in your method `SortRoomSurfData` looks correct (except it doesn't do anything)

Comment: Tnx jeroenh

This worked:

public List<SortedSurfaceData> SortRoomSurfData(List<RawSurfaceData> lstRawData)
        {
            var query = from rawData in lstRawData
    group rawData by new { rawData.idRoomElem, rawData.idElemType } into sortedData
                        select new SortedSurfaceData()
    {
        idRoomSorted = sortedData.Key.idRoomElem,
        idElemTypeSorted= sortedData.Key.idElemType,
        dblTypeArea= sortedData.Sum(x => x.dblInstArea),
    };
            List<SortedSurfaceData> sortedSurfaceData = query.ToList();
            return sortedSurfaceData;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Tnx jeroenh and miken for tips

This code worked for me.
Seems to do what it should :-)

```
public List<SortedSurfaceData> SortRoomSurfData(List<RawSurfaceData> lstRawData)
        {
            var query = from rawData in lstRawData
    group rawData by new { rawData.idRoomElem, rawData.idElemType } into sortedData
                        select new SortedSurfaceData()
    {
        idRoomSorted = sortedData.Key.idRoomElem,
        idElemTypeSorted= sortedData.Key.idElemType,
        dblTypeArea= sortedData.Sum(x => x.dblInstArea),
    };
            List<SortedSurfaceData> sortedSurfaceData = query.ToList();
            return sortedSurfaceData;
        }
```